# Select entre datas só com mês e ano

Tags: mysql

Boa noite, acredito que minha dúvida é fácil pra alguns, mas eu que sou iniciante está quebrando minha cabeça, preciso fazer uma busca com select entre as duas datas, buscando só o mês e o ano... eu fiz com o mês e funcionou, agora falta só o ano. Se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço.

```
SELECT * FROM pagamento WHERE Month(data) between '06' AND '07';
```

Ele traz os resultados  certinhos entre os meses, agora preciso que busque pelo ano. Desde de já agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: SELECT * FROM pagamento WHERE year(data) between '2014' AND '2018';

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo com isso será retornado os meses e os anos especificados e não "entre datas".

Comment: Ele traz os resultados certinhos entre os meses, agora preciso que busque pelo ano

Comment: E como é que as datas estão no banco? DATETIME, DATE ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim como você usou a função **Month** para extrair o mês, você pode usar a função **Year** para extrair o ano, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM pagamento 
WHERE Month(data) between '06' AND '07'
AND Year(data) between '2010' AND '2020';
```

**Documentação da função Year:**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

Comment: Provavelmente você teria problemas se o período desejado fosse, por exemplo, de 01/10/2019 a 29/02/2020.

Comment: @gojamex, funcionou perfeitamente, mto obrigado a tds que me ajudaram.

Comment: @Ragnar você verificou o resultado? Aparentemente esta solução só retornará datas de junho e julho, e não me parece que é o que você precisa.

Comment: @fernandosavio era isso mesmo, porque preciso escolher o periodo dos meses e ano que eu queria, por exemplo posso mudar esse select para pesquisar de junho até dezembro, se encaixou perfeitamente...mto obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @Ragnar Essa resposta não faz qualquer sentido para buscar os resultados entre datas sem considerar o dia. Esse where retornará os resultados nos MESES **E** ANOS selecionados, e não os resultados em um intervalo de datas, conforme perguntado. A única ocasião onde esse where pode ser usado é quando vc precisa dos resultados entre os meses X e Y para os anos especificados (neste caso também por um between).

Comment: Ou a pergunta está incorreta ou a resposta para ela é a https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455480/172323.

Answer (score 3):

Supondo que as datas sejam `2010-09-15` e `2020-04-08`, você poderia usar [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) para substituir o dia da data inicial por `01` e a função [`LAST_DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) para substituir o dia da data final pelo maior dia do mês. Assim você pegaria os registros dentro dos meses passados, independente do dia.

Por exemplo:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM pagamento 
WHERE data between 
    DATE_FORMAT('2010-09-15' ,'%Y-%m-01')  -- ignora o dia e usa dia 01
    AND LAST_DAY('2020-04-08');            -- ignora o dia e usa o último do mês
```

Answer (score 2):

A função DATE_FORMAT () formata uma data conforme especificado

Banco com data no formato DATETIME

```
SELECT * FROM pagamento
where DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y%m') >= DATE_FORMAT('2010-06-01 00:00:00','%Y%m') and DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y%m') <= DATE_FORMAT('2020-07-01 00:00:00','%Y%m')
```

Banco com data no formato DATE

```
SELECT * FROM pagamento
where DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y%m') >= DATE_FORMAT('2010-06-01','%Y%m') and DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y%m') <= DATE_FORMAT('2020-07-01','%Y%m')
```

Em ambos os casos você pode botar qualquer dia, e no caso de DATETIME qualquer horario que o retorno vai ser o mesmo, ou seja, seleciona entre o mes/ano. Tem que ser obrigatoriamente datas válidas, não pode botar por exemplo dia 32

Exemplo com tipo DATE

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> > Independeu dos dias informados

Answer (score 1):

Tenta Algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM PAGAMENTO 
WHERE data >= 'YYYY-MM-DD' 
AND data <= 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

Subsititui YYYY MM e DD pelo Ano, mes e Dia Inicial e Ano Mes e Dia final.
Usa Dia 01 se quer inicio do mês

Solução sem Informar o DIA:

```
    DELIMITER $

    CREATE PROCEDURE P_Busca(MESI INT, ANOI INT, MESF INT, ANOF INT)
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM PAGAMENTO
    WHERE data >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CAST(ANOI AS CHAR(4)),' ',CAST(MESI AS CHAR(2)),' ','1'),'%Y %c %e')
    AND data <= LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CAST(ANOF AS CHAR(4)),' ',CAST(MESF AS CHAR(2)),' ','05'),'%Y %c %e'));
    END $

    DELIMITER ;
```

Para Utilizara Procedure Chame ela:

```
CALL P_Busca(Mes Inicial,Ano Inicial,Mes Final, Ano Final);
```

Exemplo:

```
CALL P_BUSCA(04,2003,04,2004);
```

Vai estar de 04/2003 a 04/2004

Comment: O título da pergunta diz que tem que ser entre datas. Desta forma só retornará os anos e meses especificados.

Comment: @tvdias Favor verificar a nova solução proposta.

Comment: @marceloasr funcionou sim, só que teria ser com o mês e ano apenas?

Comment: Você pode pensar em usar as funções: 
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('YYYY', 'MM', '01'), '%Y%m%d')

E deixar o Dia fixo...

Comment: Boa! Essa é a base a se pensar! Para ganhar mais votos e a aceitação do AP, sugiro considerar que as datas são passadas por parâmetros e não poderiam ser manipuladas como vc propôs. Tente criar uma resposta onde sejam passadas 2 datas e os dias delas sejam "ignorados", ou receba duas strings no formato YYYY-MM, por exemplo, ou anos e meses separadamente.

Comment: Procure entender com o AP o que exatamente ele precisa.

Comment: Prezados, favor verificar a nova proposta de solução usando Procedure.

Comment: Da uma olhada em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455480/172323

Answer (score 1):

basta você colocar o dia como primeira dia do mes:

```
SELECT * FROM pagamento 
WHERE data >= 'YYYY-MM-01' 
AND data <= 'YYYY-MM-01';
```